# Laravel artisan command not working on CentOS 7

Tags: php, laravel, centos, command, laravel-artisan

I am trying to run php artisan commands on CentOS 7 server via SSH connection.
When I get to my project root folder and type:

```
php artisan list
```

or

```
php artisan mail:send
```

I receive the following error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /var/www/vhosts/projects/httpdocs/myproject/artisan on line 31

What should I do in order to fix this issue?

Comment: Check your server php version, laravel have few requirements you can use homestead and solve your problems.

Comment: My version is 5.4, I saw that Laravel 5.1 requires 5.5.9. But my project works on the server? I mean the web app is running perfect. What other requirements I should check?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation here is requirements